# Confusion over how the OR operator works in python

Tags: python, if-statement, types

I'm trying to see if my parameter (call it 'n') is an integer or float and returning the absolute value of n if it is an integer or float.

```
if type(n) == int or type(n) ==float:
   return abs(n)
else: 
   return "blahblah"
```

Versus

```
if type(n) == (int or float):
   return abs(n)
else:
   return "blahblah"
```

The 2nd block produces something different than I expected. What is it doing?

Comment: What error?  There is no syntax error there

Comment: "int or float" will always return "int"

Answer (score 5):

`(int or float)` will evaluate to `int` because of how the [or operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) works in Python, so `type(n) == (int or float)` is equivalent to `type(n) == int`.  So essentially the first version is checking that the type of `n` is either an `int` or `float`, and the second version is only checking if it is an `int` (in an extremely confusing way).

Note that neither of these methods are really the right way, the following is better:

```
if isinstance(n, (int, float)):
    return abs(n)
else: 
    return "blahblah"
```

Or using an [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach:

```
try:
    return abs(n)
except Exception:
    return "blahblah"
```

As a side note, the generic way to refactor `x == a or x == b` is to use `x in (a, b)`.  So in this case you could also use `if type(n) in (int, float)`, but in this case using `isinstance()` is better because it will also work properly with subclasses of `int` or `float`.

Comment: Thanks F.J! I tried using if-in which also works! if type(n) in [int,float]: But thanks for the tip

Comment: @Mei Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem. It will assist other users to know that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

return have to be in function which is start with def function:

Comment: That's the way English grammar would work if all Americans were programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Python's "and" and "or" operations will always return one of the operands - not the truth value.

Very important (and quick) read here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Both Sections 5.1 and 5.2 talk about this.

Spelling it out slowly....

```
type(n) == (int or float)
```

The first thing the interpreter must do is evaluate the expressions on both sides of the equality comparison:  '=='

if 'n' is 3.1415, we get:

```
<type 'float'> == <type 'int'>
```

The LHS is easy to see, but the RHS is what's tricky:

```
(int or float)
```

The or operator will attempt to get a boolean representation of the operands, starting with the LHS:

```
bool(int)  #yes, what is the boolean representation of the integer class?
```

Hey, it has one - you guessed right!

```
True
```

Short-circuit kicks in, and the or operator returns the operand (see docs above)

```
(int or float) #will always return <type 'int'>
```

Back to where we started:

```
<type 'float'> == <type 'int'>  #False
```

---

What you are probably looking for is the very readable:

```
if type(n) in (int, float,):
    return abs(n)
else: 
    return "blahblah"
```

Comment: There is a built-in type that has a 'False' Boolean representation.  Can you guess what it is?